# How to change the coordinates of an image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

So, I have been trying to create a platformer, but I only know so much about HTML. I have this snippet of code, and I am trying to figure out how to change the coordinates of it so I can finish my platformer.

```
var logo=document.createElement("img"); 
logo.src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"; 
document.body.appendChild(logo);
//I am using the Google Logo so you can see the image.
```

Comment: What  do you mean with changing coordinates? Do you mean dimension?

Comment: Or do you mean the position on the screen of the image?

Comment: Yeah, the position of the image on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean a position of any element in page you can do it by using below code;

```
var logo=document.createElement("img"); 
logo.src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"; 
document.body.appendChild(logo);
logo.style.position = "absolute";
logo.style.left = x_pos+'px';
logo.style.top = y_pos+'px';
```

Or do it as a function so you can attach it to an event like onmousedown

```
function placeDiv(x_pos, y_pos) {
  var logo=document.createElement("img"); 
logo.src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"; 
document.body.appendChild(logo);
  logo.style.position = "absolute";
  logo.style.left = x_pos+'px';
  logo.style.top = y_pos+'px';
}
```

Comment: might want to use `position: relative` because the other content might cause the image to be placed at a place that is hard to expect. Using relative can fine tune it

Comment: Thank you so much! i can finish creating my platformer now!